# Using UK driving license to prove age for free entry to museums in Paris

Tags: passports, france, paris, identity-cards

I'd rather use my driving license to prove my age for the concessions available to EU residents under 26 in the museums/attractions in Paris, as I don't fancy risking my passport being pickpocketed/lost.

Would this suffice? I have a UK provisional license and my partner has a full UK license.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the museum?

Answer (score 5):

For the free admission for EU residents aged 18-25 (inclusive), the proof required is an ID that has a photo (or an official EU-member state document with photo), that states your date of birth and nationality or place of residence.

Although it applies to many venues, [Musée Rodin](http://www.musee-rodin.fr/en/plan-your-visit/are-you-entitled-free-admission) expresses it more clearly.

As your UK Provisional Driving License contains all that information, it can be used as identification for admission.

Answer (score 2):

Your driving licence works fine as a proof of age when visiting the museums in Paris, as long as it states your date of birth. I've used my (Italian) driving licence countless number of times for this exact purpose. Generally speaking the admission clerk is just looking to see if you are indeed under 26 and residing EU. For these purposes any official photo ID will work.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an email enquiry to the Louvre as a [proxy to all regulated museums in Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Culture_(France)).  It took longer than expected, but the result was worth the wait...

> Dear "redacted",
>
> It is with great attention that I read your email.
>
> I inform you that in compliance with a governmental regulation, the
>   Musée du Louvre is free for visitors under the age of 18 as well as
>   for the 18-25 year-old residents of the European Economic Area. A
>   valid ID or a proof of entitlement will be required at the entrance.
>
> No ticket is required.
>
> On Friday evenings from 6 p.m. to 9:45 p.m., admission to the
>   collections is free for under-26s regardless of nationality (upon
>   presentation of the ID or the passport, a driving licence or a
>   learner’s permit can be tolerated).
>
> On the day of your visit, please join the line for visitors “with no
>   tickets” just in front of the main Pyramid.  Please note that further
>   information on the Louvre admissions and fee policy is available on
>   our website: http://www.louvre.fr/en/hours-admission You will
>   find exhaustive information on specific conditions provided to young
>   visitors.  I hope I have answered your questions and addressed your
>   concern. Please do not hesitate to contact us should you have any
>   further questions.  Yours sincerely,
>
> Name redacted,  Service de l'accueil,  Musée du Louvre

So the answer is yes, a UK driving permit (including a provisional permit) will easily suffice as a qualifying form of identification.

Museum policy in France is promulgated and regulated by the [Ministry of Culture](http://www.culturecommunication.gouv.fr/).

Answer (score 0):

Driving licences follow the same standards in all 28 EU member states as well as Iceland, Liechtenstein and Norway (while the UK is still a part of the EU) so you will be fine to use it as a form of ID in any EU member state and the 3 EFTA States I mentioned.